# How can I plot the two functions below with same color for each value of k?

Tags: plotting, functions

How can I plot the two functions below with same color for each value of k?

```
m = 10^-3;
k = {1, 5, 10, 25};
ron = 50 m;
vest[k_, M_] := k ron + ((2 + (-1 + M) M (5 + M)) ron)/(-1 + M)^2;
bb[k_, M_] := M (2 ron + k ron);
Plot[Evaluate[{vest[#, M], bb[#, M]}] & /@ k, {M, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With default colors:

```
Block[{t = Table[{vest[k1, M], bb[k1, M]}, {k1, k}]}, Plot[t, {M, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

With specified colors and styles:

```
Block[{t = Table[{vest[k1, M], bb[k1, M]}, {k1, k}]}, 
 Plot[t, {M, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thick], Red, Darker@Green, 
  Directive[Orange, Dashed]}, 
  PlotLegends -> (Row[{HoldForm@k, 
    "\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]", #}] & /@ k)]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Evaluate the complete plot-argument:

```
Show[Map[Plot[ {vest[#, M], bb[#, M]},{M,0, 1},Evaluated -> True, 
PlotStyle -> RGBColor[#/Max[k],0,1-#/Max[k]]] &, k], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: this's not what I said. I want both function vest and bb have the same color for each k like vest and bb have same red for k = 1 and same blue for k = 2 and so on

Comment: Ok, see my modiefied answer.

Comment: My color above is just an example. That color is hard to distinguish, how can I change the colors?

Comment: Perhaps you find some information in the documentation of `PlotStyle` . Try `PlotStyle -> Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, #/Max[k]]`

Answer (score 3):

```
m = 10^-3;
k = {1, 5, 10, 25};
ron = 50m;
dcr = k ron;
vest[k_, M_] := k ron + (2 + (-1 + M) M (5 + M)) ron/(-1+M)^2;
bb[k_, M_]:= (2 ron+k ron);
Plot[
 Evaluate @ Flatten @ {Map[{vest[#,M],bb[#,M]}&]@k}]
 ,{M,0,1}
 ,PlotStyle-> {Green,Green,Red,Red,Blue,Blue,Orange,Orange}
]
```

[image]

Comment: that looks nice but I don't think the curves with the same k don't have the same color.
Also you changed the bb function!

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use [`Style`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) wrappers around the individual functions. This enables you to have both data and appearance specified in the same place:

```
m = 10^-3;
k = {1, 5, 10, 25};
ron = 50 m;
vest[k_, M_] := k ron + ((2 + (-1 + M) M (5 + M)) ron)/(-1 + M)^2;
bb[k_, M_] := M (2 ron + k ron);
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  Style[
     {vest[#, M], bb[#, M]}, 
     ColorData["Rainbow"][#/Max@k]
    ] & /@ k
  ],
 {M, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Note the use of [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html), similar to the other answers.